# Ubercart 1.0 add product kit to order without checkout

Tags: product, ubercart

I want to give access to certain product kits during sign up process. I don't want user to go through checkout process. How it can be done?

Comment: Even if you gave enough information so that someone didn't have to guess at what you were asking, I doubt you'll get an answer regarding an obsolete version of a library.

Comment: I'm not able to find this functionality in Ubercart core.

I want automatically add order to user during sign up process. uc_order_save() only works for order_id. I want to save order and pass produck_kit_id as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](http://www.ubercart.org/forum/development/5647/create_new_order_user_page) answers here might help.

You might want to look at something like

```
$order = uc_order_new($uid, 'post_checkout');
```